# como faço para pegar os dados da pessoa que acabou de fazer login no meu sistema?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

a pergunta anterior eu queria saber a validação e eu ja realizei isso , agora quero saber como pego os dados da pessoa que fez login e jogue para outra tela e separar cada dado da pessoa por exemplo nome ai joga em uma textview profissao ai joga em outra textview ...

Estou tentando de varias formas diferentes mas nenhum deu certo, podem me ajudar ?

```
package com.example.scrumfacil;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private Button cadastro; 
    private Button login;
    private EditText logar;
    private EditText senha;
     Intent it;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {





            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // como colocar o usuario e senha no lugar do null

                logar =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.login);
                String logarr=logar.getText().toString();
                senha=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.senha);
                String senhaa=senha.getText().toString();


                CriaBanco validar = new CriaBanco( MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this);

                validar.validar(logarr,senhaa);

            }
        });     



        cadastro = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCadastrar);

        cadastro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent( MainActivity.this,CadastroActivity.class));

            }
        });





    }


}

    package com.example.scrumfacil;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class CadastroActivity extends Activity {

    private Button comfirmar; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro);     



        comfirmar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnComfirmarCadastro);

        comfirmar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                EditText edtN=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editNome);
                String nome1 =edtN.getText().toString();

                EditText edtU=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editUsuario);
                String usuario =edtU.getText().toString();

                EditText edts=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSenha);
                String senha =edts.getText().toString();

                EditText edtc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCpf);
                String cpf =edtc.getText().toString();

                EditText edtp=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editProf);
                String profissao =edtp.getText().toString();

                EditText edtn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editNasc);
                String nascimento =edtn.getText().toString(); 

                if(edtN.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
                       edtN.setError("Campo nome vazio");


                }else if (edtU.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){

                    edtU.setError("Campo usuario vazio");

                }           
                else if (edts.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){

                    edts.setError("Campo senha vazio");

                }           
                else if (edtc.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){

                    edtc.setError("Campo CPF vazio");

                }           
                else if (edtp.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
                    edtp.setError("Campo profissao vazio");

                }           
                else if (edtn.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){

                    edtn.setError("Campo nascimento vazio");

                }else{

                CriaBanco cb = new CriaBanco(CadastroActivity.this,CadastroActivity.this);
                cb.salvar(nome1, usuario, senha, cpf, profissao, nascimento);     


                startActivity(new Intent(CadastroActivity.this,MainActivity.class));


                    }
            }
        });



    }

}

package com.example.scrumfacil;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.OnFinished;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CriaBanco extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String NOME_BANCO = "banco.db";
    private static final int VERSAO = 1;
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
     private Activity activity;
    public CriaBanco(Context context,Activity activity) {

        super(context, NOME_BANCO, null, VERSAO);
        this.context = context;
        this.activity=  activity;   
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try{
        String sql = "create table if not exists CadastroUsuario("
                + "usuario varchar(20) primary key not null,"
                + "nome varchar(80)not null," + "senha varchar (15) not null ,"
                + "cpf integer (11)not null ,"
                + "Profissao varchar(35) not null,"
                + " nascimento date not null)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Toast.makeText(context,"Error ao criar banco",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void salvar(String nome1, String usuario, String senha, String cpf,
            String profissao, String nascimento) {

        try{

        String sql = "insert into CadastroUsuario(nome,usuario,senha,cpf,profissao,nascimento) values ('"
                + nome1
                + "','"
                + usuario
                + "','"
                + senha
                + "','"
                + cpf
                + "','"
                + profissao + "','" + nascimento + "')";
        getWritableDatabase().execSQL(sql);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.getMessage();
        Toast.makeText(context,ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    public void validar(String usuario, String senha) {
        try{
        String sql = "select usuario,senha from CadastroUsuario where usuario ='"
                + usuario + "' and senha ='" + senha + "' ";

        Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);

        if ( c.getCount()==1){

            Toast.makeText(context, "Login efetuado com sucesso",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent i = new Intent(activity,PlanejamentoActivity.class); 
        activity.startActivity(i);


        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Usuario ou senha incorreta", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        


        }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.getMessage();
        Toast.makeText(context,ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }finally{

        }




    }





    }
```

Comment: O `select` que está a utilizar para validar o `usario` e `senha` pode trazer o resto dos dados que pretende. Só necessita de alterar o `select`

Comment: eu fiz umas modificações mas ta retornando null e quando tiro o ""+ , ai fica sem nada